# Is there an easy way to install TypeScript definitions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsd

So I have been trying to use TypeScript in the last few days and I am having trouble installing definitions for external modules.

I have no problems if I use `tsd` like this:

```
tsd install express
```

However it seems that `tsd` is deprecated and I should be using `typings`.
So I try to run this command:

```
typings install --ambient express
```

This is the output:

```
typings INFO reference Stripped reference "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/serve-static/serve-static.d.ts" during installation from "express"

typings INFO reference Stripped reference "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/express-serve-static-core/express-serve-static-core.d.ts" during installation from "express"

express
└── (No dependencies)
```

Then I have to manually install the stripped references, and when I do, I still get errors when compiling with `tsc` but when I use `tsd` all references are installed and I get no errors during compiling.

I just want to install the definitions as easy as possible.
Is it safe to use `tsd` or might I run into some problems in the future?

Why doesn't `typings` install them?
Imagine if you run `npm install express` and then you get a list of dependencies and you have to recursively install all dependencies.

How much time per module should I spend just to install the definition files?

I can't find an answer online. How do other people handle this?
Also what should I do if there are no definitions available for some module?

Comment: It seems we are going to have `npm i @types/express`. It seems to work with jQuery for now. I don't know how it will handle dependencies tho. 56:28 https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B881?ocid=player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BrunoLM pointed out in the comment, with the release of TypeScript 2.0, this is the way to install declaration files now:

```
npm i @types/express
```

References:

- [TypeScript 2.0 is now available!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/09/22/announcing-typescript-2-0/)
- [Consumption - TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html)